# How to verify an answer of an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]
How to solve this problem? I think I should not just plug in the answer because the point $c$ is not continuous. I have no clue how to verify.

Is the reason of multiple solutions is that it is not locally Lipschitz？

Comment: This is an ODE, not PDE.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "the point $c$ is not continuous"?  Points are not continuous, functions are continuous.  This function is continuous and differentiable.
You certainly **do** plug in the solution to the differential equation and
check that both sides are equal.  You just have to be careful in verifying it at the point $t=c$.

Yes, the reason it doesn't contradict the theorem is that the right side of the equation is not locally Lipschitz.